# Inconsistencies in the Action on Google Javadoc and samples

Tags: java, kotlin, javadoc, actions-on-google

I'm reading [Java Actions on Google](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java) [JavaDocs](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-java/com/google/actions/api/response/ResponseBuilder.html) where the mentions of this pattern are shown:

ResponseBuilder builder = getResponseBuilder()

whereas the [reference for the DialogflowApp](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-java/com/google/actions/api/DialogflowApp.html) only mentions the following getter:

```
ResponseBuilder getResponseBuilder(ActionRequest request)
```

but not the one without a parameter.

Also, note a missing semicolon in the former `getResponseBuilder()` call.  Are these samples given in Java or in Kotlin?

Are the above examples a normal behavior, inconsistencies, or simple omissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [the examples](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java/blob/f25eed0397f38331c38d651897f4058843ccd8bf/src/main/kotlin/com/google/actions/api/response/ResponseBuilder.kt#L35) are written in Java, although it is definitely possible that the comments are outdated or based on an earlier version of the code.

You can file an issue on the library [through GitHub](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java/issues/new).